# Stats on handling my spam flags across the network

Tags: feature-request, flags, spam, network-profile, network-statistics

I am flagging spam posts detected by [SmokeDetector](https://github.com/charcoal-se/smokedetector), and I want to see the network wide impact on flagging the spam.

Spam content is getting deleted immediately from the sites like MSE, SO. Response from other Stack Exchange sites is very slow. Sometimes, it takes hours to remove the spam content.

It's very difficult to remember on which site I have flagged posts.

**How do I track down my flags status?**
How about having an "impact" tab in the network profile page which shows the flag status from all SE sites ?
[image: network tab]

Comment: `flag-summary` works for a single SE site. When I applied this URL logic on network profile page, `http://stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/6017184/` → **Page not found**.

Comment: Understood, 'feature-request' tag added to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the flow you're describing here. At what point are you running into uncertainty about whether a particular post has been flagged or not? Or is this just a general stats-gathering process to compare sites' response times?

Comment: @NathanTuggy, When I flag a spam post in SO or MSE, within the next 10-15 min,  my flag will be marked as -'helpful' & light red color background(indicating post deleted) in profile→flag-summary page. This is not the case with most the of SE sites, it takes time to delete the spam, which makes it difficult to track down.

Comment: @Raju: Yes, I know how flagging works, but what's the difficulty in tracking it down? That's the part I don't get. Just open every probably-spam post once, flag it once, and move on, right?

Comment: I am suggesting a feature to see the network wide impact on flagging the spam.

Comment: Fair enough, but it was already suggested. (i.e. dupe.)